# Tkinter Adjusting widget from outside the class?

Tags: python, class, variables, tkinter

sorry please bear with me i'm struggling. i've searched and i dont fully understand where i'm going wrong even though there are already posts covering the exact subject.

The short story is im running a process and is it runs through said process i want the text to change to red from black as it runs through. Now the way i am trying to do this is from outside of the classs.

If i can draw your attention to def C(): 
once the program has started from the start button, variable start is set to 1. i want the text in Application.createWidgets() under message statusStartTk to change to red. I am trying to do this in C() with Application.statusStartTk.config(fg='red')

Now its probably obvious to you clever guys where i'm going wrong and would appreciate being put right. i've spent a few hours trying different things and searching to no avail. You can probably see where i've commented bits and bobs out where i've been trying things.

Also i'd just like to say i appreciate the very fast and helpful responses you guys are coming back with so far, so thank you, again, and in anticipation.

anyway, here's the code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as Tk
import tkinter

#sets up Tkinter GuI
root = Tk.Tk()

#Set Adjustable Variables for GUI
startText=StringVar()
startText.set("Start Brew!")



def a():
    #print('a')
    print('start = ', start)

def b():
    print('b')

def c(): #GUI ASSISTANCE STATUS WINDOW
    print('c')
    if start==1:
        Application.statusStartTk.config(fg='red')



def main():
    a()
    b()
    c()   

class Application(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        #Set start buttons and sink and disable if brew started
        self.startButton = Tk.Button(root, textvariable=startText, command=Application.startBrew)
        self.startButton.place(x=902,y=60)

        #Plant Status List
        statusTitle = "Plant Status Update:"
        statusTitleTk = Message(root,width=200,font=("Tk Default Font",16), text=statusTitle)
        statusTitleTk.place(x=1090,y=40)

        statusStart = "- Brew Started"
        statusStartTk = Message(root,width=200, text=statusStart)
        statusStartTk.place(x=1100,y=70)


        self.onUpdate()

    def startBrew():
        print('brew has started')
        global start,startButton
        start=1
        startText.set("Brew Started")
        Application()

    def onUpdate(self): 
        root.update_idletasks()
        main()
        #str(variable1.get())
        self.after(5, self.onUpdate)

app = Application(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Taken as much as i think i can out without confusing things if this helps? the main thing im trying to do is in C() change font of statusStartTk which is in Application.createWidgets()

Comment: What you can do is change `statusTitleTk` to `self.statusTitleTk`. And call it by `app.statusStartTk.config(fg='red')`.

Comment: Thank You Very Much - still not grasping the concept of the use of self.

Comment: One other thing you should change it to remove this: `self.createWidgets()` from `__init__` and do `app.createWidgets()` after `app = Application(master=root)`. Since it's not recommanded to have a chain of functions in `__init__`

Comment: And you usually don't want to import tkinter 3 times, just use `import tkinter as tk` as this is the most common and preferred way. but if your lazy, you can also include this: `from tkinter.constants import *` which will import all the CAPITALIZED words tkinter use.

Comment: I'm pretty new so i've butchered a lot of code i've found online. I intend on a tidy up once i've got it doing what i want it to. Quick one, made the ammendments and when setting start to 1, and C tries to change font i get the following:

Comment: Application.statusStartTk.config(fg='red')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'statusStartTk'

Comment: What I meant was to change  `statusTitle` to `self.statusTitle` and `statusStart` to `self.statusStart` and everything else.., sorry for not being clear. This will make them all instance of `app`

Comment: Done, thanks again abccd, taken a little while for that to sink in. obviously need to slow down a touch and make sure i properly understand. all changes made and working a treat. Cheers

Comment: appreciate it, i'm learning all the time but with no instruction and short time frames i'm heavily reliant upon the help and understanding of people like yourself!